# Why this code is not working on blogspot site?

Tags: tags, conditional-statements

I want to show Google's Adsense ads only on desktop and not on mobile phone.
But the code that I use for it, does not work at all.

Anybody help me

```html
<b:if cond='data:mobile == &quot;false&quot;'>
Adsense ad code goes here..
</b:if>
```